# Is it possible to import an image into canvas from a different domain that does not support CORS

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, cors

I want to import a picture from a different domain that does not support CORS. The picture is supposed to go into canvas so I can change the colors.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: well, you can use an `<img>` tag from a different domain, without cors...maybe you can extract the data from an `<img>` tag somehow?L

Comment: You can always import a picture from any domain you want. The only problem is that you won't be able to grab the colors from your canvas if the image isn't from the same domain.

Comment: exactly, that's what I mean, I tried to use this plugin here but it didn't work http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/#download

Comment: @klausruprecht There is no possible way to get away with the same origin policy. What you can do though, is to grab the image from your server and pass it to the page.

Comment: CORS is currently required for valid security reasons so programmatically loading an image from a different domain will taint the canvas and prevent `getImagedata` from fetching your pixel colors. @Derek朕會功夫 has one workaround (route the image through your server). Another workaround is to have the user download the image to their local drive and use either `FileReader` or `input type=file` to fetch the image in a CORS compliant way. (This other workaround is CORS compliant because the user is confirming that they allow the foreign image to be loaded).

Comment: @markE I'm curious though, what if I pass the image in through the drag and drop API? That might also be a method to get around the policy.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Well, you can certainly enter an `http://somewhere.com/image.png` URL when using `input type=file`. You can also drag an image file from the **local disk** when using FileReader. But I'm unaware of any way to drag an image from a different domain (eg from another open browser tab) in a CORS compliant way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No. Only if you use a proxy or some such. Otherwise it would violate the same-origin policy.